# Array of bytearrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, packing

I have a class that has multiple, multiple length byte arrays in it as well as a create buffer function which stitches them all together:

```
class message():
    msg_hdr_ONE = bytearray(b'\x00')
    msg_hdr_TWO = bytearray(b'\x00')
    msg_hdr_THREE = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')
    msg_hdr_FOUR  = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')

def createBuffer(self):
    self.byteArrays = bytearray()
    self.byteArrays.extend(self.msg_hdr_ONE )
    self.byteArrays.extend(self.msg_hdr_TWO)
    self.byteArrays.extend(self.msg_hdr_THREE )
    self.byteArrays.extend(self.msg_hdr_FOUR  )
    return byteArrays
```

My question is: Is it possible to wrap all the global bytearrays into an array so I can just call

```
    self.byteArrays.extend(arrayOfBytearrays)
```

instead of extending the bytearray one by one.

FYI: Later on in the code i call, for example:

```
 myMessage.msg_hdr_THREE[1] = 0x0B
 myMessage.createBuffer()
```

to change the class member variables and send the data over the network.

Thanks

EDIT:
self.**dict**.vales() gives me the correct number of bytes held in the class but in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is probably a list and adding all header parts with `b''.join()`:

```
class Message():
    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = [bytearray(b'\x00'),
                        bytearray(b'\x00'), 
                        bytearray(b'\x00\x00'),
                        bytearray(b'\x00\x00')]

    def createBuffer(self):
        return b''.join(self.headers)
```

Indexing start at `0`. Therefore, modifying the first byte in header `THREE` would be the index `[2][0]`:

```
>>> mymessage = Message()
>>> mymessage.createBuffer()
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> mymessage.headers[2][0] = 0x0B
>>> mymessage.createBuffer()
b'\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the message is insanely long (500 -600) bytes and so using mymessage.headers[152][3] for example doesn't really give any indication to the user of the class what he's editing. For that reason i would like to keep the naming convention objectName.memberVariableName

Comment: How would you like `[152][2] ` to look like, `msg_hdr_HUNDREDFIFTYONE[4]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to use sum or itertools.chain.from_iterable in the create buffer function (or reduce,  but its quite deprecated) :

With sum:

```
class Message(object):
    self.msg_hdr_ONE = bytearray(b'\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_TWO = bytearray(b'\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_THREE = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_FOUR  = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')

def createBuffer(self):
    byteArrays = bytearray(
        sum((
            self.msg_hdr_ONE,
            self.msg_hdr_TWO,
            self.msg_hdr_TREE,
            self.msg_hdr_FOUR,

        ),
        bytearray()
    ))

    return byteArrays
```

Note that the second parameter is the first argument to be sumed,  so a TypeError won't be raised

With itertools.chain.from_iterable:

```
import itertools

class Message(object):
    self.msg_hdr_ONE = bytearray(b'\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_TWO = bytearray(b'\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_THREE = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')
    self.msg_hdr_FOUR  = bytearray(b'\x00\x00')

def createBuffer(self):
    byteArrays = bytearray(
        itertools.chain.from_iterable((
            self.msg_hdr_ONE,
            self.msg_hdr_TWO,
            self.msg_hdr_TREE,
            self.msg_hdr_FOUR,

    )))

    return byteArrays
```

(i think ''.join() won't work here since these are bytes array, but you should check it out to make sure :))

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in both cases you still have to pack the buffer one member variable at a time. I'm looking for a way to do this in one line so that adding a new message field is only done in the Message Class and createBuffer packs everything in the Message Class